# Display Json data using PHP

Tags: php, arrays, json

I have a json file and I want to display its data in a PHP file. I use the below code but it gives me error.

```
$json = file_get_contents('data.json'); 
$data = json_decode($json);
foreach ($data as $value)
  {
  echo "$value[1]<br>";
  }
```

**data.json** file contains data in this format.

```
{
"users":[
{"id":"03B7F72C1A522631","user":"test1@gmail.com"}, 
{"id":"27EB9CE8338083AE","user":"test2@gmail.com"}, 
{"id":"E27854ABBFF8CD92","user":"test3@gmail.com"}],
"status":
    {
    "version":"0.9.5.0",
    "command":"listusers",
    "opf":"json",
    "error":false,
    "code":0
    }
}
```

I want the Output as

```
User ID | User Email

03B7F72C1A522631 | test1@gmail.com
27EB9CE8338083AE | test2@gmail.com
```

Comment: `json_decode($json, true);` add second parameter if you want to use as array.

Comment: What do you mean by "it gives me error"? Is there any error message which you've forgot to share?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
$json = file_get_contents('data.json'); 
$data = json_decode($json,true);
$users=$data['users'];
for($users as $user)
{
   echo $user['id']." ".$user['user'];
}
$status=$data['status'];
```

Answer (score 0):

Use this which will give an associative array instead of an object

```
$data = json_decode($json,true);
```

for details have a look here [json_decode function](https://www.php.net/json_decode)

Comment: Now it gives this output "Array"

Comment: print_r($data) and see the full array

Comment: Thanks for your help, I update the question and I mentioned the desired output

Answer (score 0):

> get data from json file

```
$homepage = file_get_contents('url');

$someArray = json_decode($homepage, true);

foreach ($someArray as $key => $value) {
    echo "\nAddress: " . $value["address"] . "\n\n";
}
```

Comment: Can you explain that further? What makes you think that your code solves the mysterious error?